# Python scripting. Classes or functions?

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, automation, scripting

I have been writing some python scripts to automate some tasks at work for quite some time now. Each time, the script follows the same pattern, of main calling different functions(which in turn call other) and controlling the overall flow:

```
def func2(aws_client, xyz_client, var1, var2, dict1, dict2):
   ...

def func1(aws_client, xyz_client, var1, var2, dict1):
   ...
   func2(aws_client, xyz_client, var1, var2, dict1, dict2)

def main():
  func1(aws_client, xyz_client, var1, var2, dict1)
```

While this works fine, I end up seeing myself passing multiple same parameters in particular order between functions and find it hard to maintain and keep track.
I read in a few places that taking a class based approach might help. ie, all the shared state are just members of the class and to access/set them by self.aws_client etc.

However, since I am mainly automating stuff, its hard to think of this as a Class(something as a real world object/an entity). So in this case, are we using classes just as a workaround for shares data? Are there some best practices to follow for such scripts?

Comment: Best practice runs the gambit from everything's a class (Java), to we don't need no stickin` classes (go). So, any answer here is highly opinionated. If your functions don't really logically group together, then don't just make classes to try to avoid a little typing. That doesn't work in python anyway because you'll just be typing "self" all of the time. IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. I might go ahead with using functions but making a little smarter functions so that I am not passing the same arguments to multiple functions each time.

Comment: One option is a simple `dict` holding commonly needed stuff. Functions are free to use whatever bits they want. This is much like a class except that functions can be in multiple modules and doing unrelated stuff. That's commonly how things are done in C and that's fundamental to how Go is designed. As a `dict` (or a simple class holding only data), the functions are only loosely bound.

Comment: If all your functions need all the variables you are probably using quite a bad design. Don't split the functions into chronological parts; see functions as a piece of code, that only  has one single task and name them accordingly. Example: `create_connection(client)`, `dict2 = do_calculation(var1, var2, dict1)`, `upload_result(client, dict2)`. This leads to well readable code and the functions will only need a few parameters.